# Does call_backs with same name in parent and child classes need not to be called again

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I had two methods with same name which is present in both parent and child class. But I the callback before_filter: method_name is called only in parent class and the before_filter: is not present in child class. But load_object is called in child class without call_back itself.

```
class Parent
  before_filter: call

  def call
    #
  end
end

class child < Parent
  def call
    # But the method is called here without call_back
  end
end
```

There is no class is inherited from child.

Answer (score 0):

When you define a method in a child class, this overrides any method by the same name in the parent class. (This is a basic principle in Object Oriented Programming; it is in no way specific to ruby/rails.)

`before_filter: :call` is saying: "Execute the method `call`, before any controller action".

The `Child` class inherits the `before_filter` behaviour, but overrides the `call` method. Therefore its own implementation of `call` is being executed.

---

I cannot really advise how to change your code, because I don't know what you're trying to achieve. But hopefully that explains why you're experiencing this (correct) behaviour.

Comment: okay then, all the call_backs behaviour are inherited in child class is that correct. @Tom  Lord

Comment: The callbacks are inherited, yes. Just like everything else is. But as I said, if you override a method definition then you may change what code is executed by the callback.

Comment: If you want to "cancel" the callback in the `Child` class, you can use: `skip_before_filter :call`. Or if you want to trigger the original method inside `Child#call`, you can use `super`. Or if you don't want to change the behaviour, then you shouldn't define a new method with the same name. As I said though, I can't really suggest what you "should" do, without knowing what you're trying to achieve.